# vue3 and vite.js, docker build production failed "Error: Could not resolve entry module (index.html)."

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vuejs3, rollupjs, vite

I am trying to build a vue3 project with vite.js. I want to build it in a Dockerfile, but I get the following error.

```sh
vite v2.9.5 building for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
Could not resolve entry module (index.html).
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve entry module (index.html).
    at error (/panda-planner/frontend-planner/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:198:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (/panda-planner/frontend-planner/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22480:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream
```

I have been looking for information on rollup but I don't understand what it is. Also my command `npm run build` works perfectly on my computer.

Can someone help me, please?

My vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import eslintPlugin from "vite-plugin-eslint";

const path = require("path");

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), eslintPlugin()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
});
```

My Dockerfile

```
# Build backend application
FROM node:14.19.1-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /panda-planner/backend-planner/
COPY /backend-planner/package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "run", "start" ]

# Build frontend application
FROM builder as frontend
WORKDIR /panda-planner/frontend-planner/
COPY /frontend-planner/package*.json .
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Setup nginx server for frontend
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as nginx
COPY --from=frontend /frontend-planner/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
#COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad -_-!

I made a mistake in the COPY path in the frontend.

This solution works:

```
# Build backend application
FROM node:14.19.1-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /panda-planner/backend-planner/
COPY /backend-planner/package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY /backend-planner/ .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "run", "start" ]

# Build frontend application
FROM builder AS frontend
WORKDIR /panda-planner/frontend-planner/
COPY /frontend-planner/package*.json .
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY /frontend-planner/ .
RUN npm run build

# Setup nginx server for frontend
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS nginx
COPY --from=frontend /panda-planner/frontend-planner/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
#COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Comment: There are many COPY commands here. Please specify which one was problematic.